# Solution for backing up/copying from multiple destinations

Tags: debian, backup, cron

We have 12 Debian servers that we want to copy a specific directory from to just one server on a weekly basis. This server will act as sort of a backup server.

Any suggestions how to go about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A combination of rsync, ssh and some basic bash scripting is the way to go. It's not complex.

Answer (score 1):

Rsnapshot is the way to go. Rsnapshot is just as easy to setup as your own rsync commands and will add some nice flexibility. http://rsnapshot.org/. Rsnapshot will automatically create versions of your backup, but only a relatively small amount of additional storage (the deltas)

You will need to setup ssh keys to do any kind of copy securely.

Answer (score 0):

I'll recommend you to keep in mind that you can have **multiple rsnapshot configuration files** and then call them from your **crontabs** or anacrontabs.

```
rsnapshot -c /etc/your_config_file_for_servers1
rsnapshot -c /etc/your_config_file_for_servers2
```

For doing it securely over network go through **ssh if you need encrypted data**, otherwise through **nfs**.

If you need to backup a workstation or server which is not always up, take a look @ [anacron](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/anacron.8.html)

Answer (score 0):

[Rocknroll](https://github.com/JacquelinCharbonnel/rocknroll.git) is a light alternative.

To use it, first, prepare an archive point on the destination server (one shot). For example :

```
rocknroll --init 7 daily /var/snapshots
rocknroll --init 4 weeky /var/snapshots
```

prepare the directory `/var/snapshots` for a set of 7 series of archives named `daily`, and a set of 4 series of archives named `weekly`.

After that, yo can perform daily and weekly backup. To do a weekly backup  :

```
rocknroll weekly root@remote.my.domain:/home /var/snapshots
```

This perfoms a rsync from `remote.my.domain:/home` into `/var/snapshots/weekly.1/`
A second :

```
rocknroll weekly root@remote.my.domain:/home /var/snapshots
```

rename `/var/snapshots/weekly.1/` to `/var/snapshots/weekly.2/`, and   perfoms a new rsync from `remote.my.domain:/home` into `/var/snapshots/weekly.1/` (with file deduplication between the 2 directories).

4 archives will be kept : `/var/snapshots/weekly.1/` to `/var/snapshots/weekly.4/`.

Comment: Please disclose directly that you are the author of this script.

Comment: It would also be a good idea to provide an example usage, perhaps related to the original question.